# ERROR; SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, javascript, html

He creado una web donde contempla consulta a una base de datos montada en phpmyadmin, la he estado realizando en local y cuando la he montado en el server, me sale este errro: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`, paso a detallar el proceso, tengo dos select el segundo es dependiente o dínamico del primero pues según la informacón que seleccionemos filtra opciones para el segundo las opciones de selección la toman de una consulta a una BD a través de script con lenguaje javascript adjunto código:

```
                    $("#cbx_dia").change(function () {
                        $("#cbx_dia option:selected").each(function () {
                            id_dia = $(this).val();
                            $.post("includes/getTipoDia.php", { id_dia: id_dia }, function(data){
                                $("#cbx_tipoDia").html('');
                                data = JSON.parse(data);
                                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                    var opcion = data[i];
                                    $("#cbx_tipoDia").append("<option value='"+opcion.id+"'>"+opcion.valor+"</option>");
                                }
                            });            
                        });
                    })
            });
```

el fallo lo recibo en la linea `data = JSON.parse(data);`
algo ocurre que no recibe bien el json, y no se si lo contruye mal pues el código creo que no hay errores, lo curioso es que en localhost va perfecto.
Paso el archvimos getTipoDie.php que hace la consulta.

```
<?php
    require ('../conexion.php');

    $id_dia = $_POST['id_dia'];

    $query = "SELECT id_tipoDia, NombreTipoDia FROM DiaTipo WHERE dia_id = '$id_dia' ORDER BY NombreTipoDia";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);

    $html= "<option value=''>Tipo de día</option>";
    // devolvamos un array
    $tipoDia = [['id' => '', 'valor' => 'Tipo de día']];
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){//recorremos el parámetro de la consulta
        // Se utiliza el utf8_encode() para castear el cotejamiento de los strings y así corregir los caracteres especiales
        $tipoDia[] = ['id' => $row['id_tipoDia'], 'valor' => ($row[utf8_encode('NombreTipoDia')])];
    }

    echo json_encode($tipoDia);
?>
```

espero vuestra ayuda y gracias de antemano.

Un saludo

Comment: Puedes mostrar el json que te genera? Esto `($row[utf8_encode('NombreTipoDia')])` tiene todas las papeletas de ser el problema... Creo que deberías poner el utf8_encode fuera y no dentro del $row...

Comment: Es correcto era un error de sintaxis, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Puede imprimir un console.log(data) para ver si envía algo